# "fill in" .vrt with missing locations in a mosaic

Tags: gdal, mapnik

I have ~2000 NASA SRTM .hgt files.  I wanted to join them together in a single mosaic, and to save disk space I used GDAL to create a .VRT rather than a very large GeoTiff.  This is read by Mapnik.

What I would like to do is "fill in" the areas in the mosiac that aren't covered by one of the original .hgt files.  In other words, I want to pretend as if those uncovered areas are actually covered by a .hgt that has a constant value for all data points.  Thus, the resulting .VRT will be able to report a value for those areas.  (or, if I end up making a .tif instead of .vrt, the .tif would have a value for each of those areas).

Is this possible?

(to elaborate: the reason I want to do this is because I am generating tiles to cover the entire world - this will be an overlay, not base tiles.  My data does not cover everywhere, and for the areas that it doesn't cover I want to be able to style it in a particular color.  Normally, I could use Mapnik's 'background-color' attribute, and it would color any background area in the map.  However, one of my styles for the data areas I want to cover is transparent, and setting the background-color would erroneously fill in the transparent areas.  Hence, my desire to modify the data set)

Comment: I am not sure but perhaps the last example in page http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html about using -vrtnodata could work for you.

Comment: Thank you - I saw that option, but I don't think it does quite what I want.  It would allow me to control how nodata is handled within my images, and what I want is to add to the final image all of the area that is not covered by the original images.

Comment: Did you try it? If I understand it right it serves color that you define as vrtnodata when there are no data in vrt.